# OCaml "This 'struct' might be unmatched"

Tags: ocaml

Here is my code:

```ocaml
module type Queue =
  sig
    type element
    type queue
    exception EMPTY_Q
    val emptyQ: queue
    val enQ: queue * element -> queue
    val deQ: queue -> element * queue
  end

module IntListQ =
  struct
    type element = int list
    type queue = (int list * int list)
    exception EMPTY_Q
    let emptyQ = queue
    let enQ = queue * element -> queue
    let deQ = queue -> element * queue
  end
```

This is the error I got:

> `Error: This 'struct' might be unmatched.`

Not sure why I am getting this error. I feel like it has to do with using a special keyword that is predefined in OCaml but I don't really know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the sublanguage for types (notably the `->` symbol) inside your struct, which is supposed to be an implementation.

E.g., this is not a function definition:

```
let enQ = queue * element -> queue
```

But it's supposed to be one.